# Mongoose discriminator doesnt work with embedded collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my base schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var utils= require("util");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function BaseSchema(){
    Schema.apply(this, arguments);

    this.add({
        name: String,
        description: String,


    })

};

utils.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);

module.exports = BaseSchema;
```

This is my model with the embedded BaseSchema:

```
    var StepSchema = require('./step')
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        description: String,
        steps: [new StepSchema()]

    });

    schema.plugin(timestamps);

    var Funnel = mongoose.model('Funnel', schema);

    module.exports = Funnel;
```

And now whenever I save a record like these:

```
var funnel = new Funnel(req.body);
funnel.steps.push(new ActionStep({name: "test",actionType: "Notification"}));
funnel.save(function(err, b){
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).end();
            };

            res.json({funnel:b});

        });
```

The discrimator key is not saved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use discriminator on `Funnel` model and then on saving it will include discriminated fields, like just after creating Funner model, we can define discriminator:

```
var StepSchema = require('./step')
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    steps: [new StepSchema()]

});

schema.plugin(timestamps);

var bossSchema = new BaseSchema({ name: String, actionType: String }); 

var Funnel = mongoose.model('Funnel', schema);

var Boss = Funnel.discriminator('Boss', bossSchema)
```

Now, while saving record:

```
var boss = new Boss({name: "test", actionType: "Notification" });
boss.save(function(err,boss) {

     if (err) {
            res.status(500).end();
        };

  });
var funnel = new Funnel(req.body);
funnel.steps.push(boss);
funnel.save(function(err, b){
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).end();
        };

        res.json({funnel:b});

    });

Which will produce output like this:

Boss:
{
"__v": 0,
"name": "test",
"actionType": "Notification",
"__t": "Boss",
"_id": "54a1951210a7a1b60316111a"
}

Funnel:
{
"steps":[
"__v": 0,
"name": "test",
"actionType": "Notification",
"__t": "Boss",
"_id": "54a1951210a7a1b60316111a"
]
}
```

As you can see, there is a different structure for Boss, notably the _t property as well as other defined properties for the different objects. however actually stored in the same "steps" collection and can be queried as such.

So check your collection for existing documents that vary from your schema definition, and consider the approach as shown to represent a "polymorphic" association for different "types" of objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of my base schema:

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Business = require('../models/business');
    var BusinessProductCategory = require('../models/businessProductCategory');
    var MasterProduct = require('../models/masterProduct');

    var common = require('../middlewares/common');

    var nameMinLength = [3, 'The value of path `{PATH}` (`{VALUE}`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length ({MINLENGTH}).'];

    var options = {discriminatorKey: 'kind'};

    var businessProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        business: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business'},
        productPrices: [{
            value: {type: Number, required: true},
            currency: {type: String, required: true},
            description: {type: String, required: true},
            createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
            updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true}
        }],
        is_show_in_store: {type: Boolean, default: true, required: true},
        record_status: {type: String, enum: ['active', 'archived'], required: true, default: 'active'},
    }, options);

    businessProductSchema.post('save', common.handlerMongoErrors);
    businessProductSchema.post('update', common.handlerMongoErrors);

    var BusinessProduct = mongoose.model("BusinessProduct", businessProductSchema);

    var ManagedProduct = BusinessProduct.discriminator('ManagedProduct', new mongoose.Schema({
        master_product: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MasterProduct'},
    }), options);

    var LocalProduct = BusinessProduct.discriminator('LocalProduct', new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true, minlength: nameMinLength},
        description: {type: String},
        primary_category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BusinessProductCategory'},
        brand: {type: String, required: true},
        created_at: {type: Date, required: true},
        updated_at: {type: Date, required: true},
    }, options));

    module.exports = {BusinessProduct: BusinessProduct, ManagedProduct: ManagedProduct, LocalProduct: LocalProduct};
```